# PDO expecting all results to show up but only one shows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to execute a statement where it will show all of the results for each row of my table but all it is doing is showing the results from the last row.

```
<?php
    require_once('php/dbconfig.php');

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $name = array($row['user_name']);
        $email = array($row['user_email']);
    }
    echo $name[0];
?>
```

This will work but it will only echo out the name of the last person in my table. If I try to replace the 0 with any other number nothing will show.

I would like to be able to show all users and emails in a list.

Comment: Looks like you may be reusing the same variable and overwriting the value. Try echoing within the loop. I also don't see where you set `$title` so I am surprised you see anything.

Comment: `$name[] = $row['user_name'];`

Comment: @ToothlessRebel `$title` was a typo. I unfortunately have too many tabs open right now.

Comment: @splash58 Thank it works like a charm!

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following block you are assigning each name to the variable `$name`.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $name = array($row['user_name']);
    $email = array($row['user_email']);
}
```

I think you intend to either echo `$name` each iteration of the loop by adding the echo to the loop as:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $name = $row['user_name'];
    $email = $row['user_email'];
    echo "{$name} - {$email}";
}
```

or to add it to an array of names by changing the assignment from `$name` to `$name[]` which means 'the next index of the `$name` array'.

Fetch also returns one record, so you'll need to loop the results or change to fetchAll as suggested by other answers.

Comment: `$name` and `$email` should not be arrays, I don't think. If they are the echo should address their index.

Comment: Your answer yields `Array - ArrayArray - ArrayArray - ArrayArray - ArrayArray - ArrayArray - ArrayArray - ArrayArray - Array`

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy You are correct, the issue was adding them to an array with `array()` which I didn't notice when copying and pasting your code.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy I have removed what assigned it to an array. If you were getting multiple instances this should work now. Keep in mind you may need to alter the `echo` statement to format correctly. I don't have spaces or line breaks between each output.